# Help to convert PostgreSQL dates into SQL Server dates

Tags: sql-server, regex, datetime

Hello I'm doing some data conversion from PostgreSQL to Microsoft SQL Server. So far it has all went well and I almost have the entire database dump script running. There is only one thing that is now messed up: dates.

The dates are dumped to a string format. These are two example formats I've seen so far: `'2008-01-14 12:00:00'` and the more precise `'2010-04-09 12:23:45.26525'`

I would like a regex (or set of regexs) that I could run so that will replace these with SQL Server compatible dates. Anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is compatible with `datetime`, but the second is too precise.  It will fit in `sqldatetime2`, which is available from SQL Server 2008:

```
select cast('2008-01-14 12:00:00' as datetime)
,      cast('2010-04-09 12:23:45.26525' as datetime2)
```

For an earlier version, you can use `substring` to chop off the unstorable precision:

```
select cast(substring('2010-04-09 12:23:45.26525',1,23) as datetime)
```

For a regex to remove any additional digits (using perl regex syntax):

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})\d*
```

And replace with:

```
$1
```

Which is matches the regex part between `()` brackets.

Comment: Changing our datetime columns to sqldatetime2 is not an option though. We do not need the extra precision, it's just that timestamp is the only datetime-ish format in PostgreSQL

Comment: @Earlz: If you don't need the extra precision, use `substring` to remove it.  SQL Server recognizes the `HH:mm:ss.fff` format for microseconds

Comment: Yes but your solution is not complete. I'm dealing with a multi thousand line file. What would be a regex to match this date so I can replace it with a `cast(substring... ` bit?

Comment: @Earlz: SQL Server does not support regexes... in what language would you like to do the regex replace?  Have you tried SQL Server's text import wizard, which is fairly powerful?

Comment: @Ando no I have a huge text file containing the SQL code dumped from a PostgreSQL database. I am converting the text so that I can restore the data from Postgres to SQL Server. The regex only needs to run in a text editor.

Comment: @Earlz: Added a perl compat regex